# Specifying that LocalObject should use MX

Tags: export, import

.mx is blazingly fast relative to .wl(.m)

Unfortunately, it is not terribly portable. Word-on-the-street is that it's cross-system compatible, but not necessarily cross-version or even cross-point-version compatible (although I haven't tested this).

Likely for that reason, `LocalObject` uses .wl to store objects.

Now, I can make it use .mx like so:

```
Block[{LocalObjects`$objectFile = "object.mx"},
   Put[1, LocalObject["test/a"]]
   ];

Block[{LocalObjects`$objectFile = "object.mx"},
 Get[LocalObject["test/a"]]
 ]

1
```

But this <s>feels</s> is unstable and hacky.

Is there a better way?

Comment: It is cross-version compatible, but only forward: later versions read earlier MX.  Since some recent release, this goes both ways. Earlier M can read MX written by later M provided that no new expression types are used.  However, it is not 32/64-bit cross-compatible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about `Import/Export`?:

```
Export[LocalObject["test/a"], 1, "MX"];


Import[LocalObject["test/a"], "MX"]
```

> 1

```
Import[LocalObject["test/a"], "Text"]
```

> (*This is a Wolfram Language binary dump file. It can be loaded with \
>   Get.*)
>
> ...
>
> (*End of Wolfram Language binary dump file*)